# Do watches break very often for some people?

Tags: consumer-products, electromagnetism

I know of someone who cannot seem to wear watches without them breaking much quicker than expected.

This person was told it is because their body is producing too much electricity and that by putting nail polish on the reverse of the watch to block the current the watch would work.

See also this straight dope thread:

> I've heard people claim that wrist watches stop working for them after a very short period of time. They replace the batteries, switch watch brands and styles, etc., but to no avail -- every watch quits on them. Even when well taken care of and not dropped, damaged, or submerged, they seem to die after a few months of wearing them.

([Why do wrist watches stop working for some people?](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=545968))

Is it true that, for some people, wrist watches break very often?

Comment: I know of people with metal allergy put nail polish on them, to avoid the direct skin contact.

Comment: I know people who are rougher on *everything* than other people - everything they own lasts less long than it "should"